# In shell I can reference google.cloud but not in Spyder

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

On a Windows machine I have installed Anaconda Spyder.

In the shell I do:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages>pip show google-cloud
Name: google-cloud
Version: 0.32.0
Summary: API Client library for Google Cloud
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-pyt
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
```

I start Spyder.  I add an entry in the PYTHONPATH to match the "Location" in the above.  I restart the kernel in Spyder.  WHen I attempt

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

I get

```
$ from google.cloud import bigquery
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-1765a8225e71>", line 1, in <module>
from google.cloud import bigquery

ImportError: No module named google.cloud
```

What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure Spyder is using Anaconda2 and not Anaconda3?

Comment: Sorry if I'm getting this wrong, but shouldn't you install the package via the "conda" command if you're using Anaconda? Also, wouldn't it be easier for you to use WinPython if you want a Spyder dev environment? I got WinPython installed on my machine, ran its command-line, installed google-cloud via its "pip" and it worked without issues.

Comment: Behind a corporate proxy I do  "pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org <packagename> "     I do not know what equivalent command there is in conda to deal with the proxy.

Comment: I've installed the latest version of Anaconda on another Windows machine; turns out Anaconda's package manager command doesn't have the "google-cloud" package available for Windows, only Linux and macOS. Try running the "pip install" command inside an "Anaconda Prompt"; search for the prompt in your Start Menu and make sure to run it as an Administrator. I did just that and was able to use the package without issues on Spyder.

Comment: I'd make sure there is a reference to the `google` module in your `PYTHONPATH`.